# Cannot find module 'firebase-functions/lib/encoder' from 'node_modules/firebase-functions-test/lib/providers/firestore.js'

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Hey I am trying to unit test this cloud function right here:

```
import { logger, region, https } from "firebase-functions/v1";
import Message from "../types/message";

const helloWorldHandler = region("europe-west1").https.onCall((_, context) => {
  if (context.app == undefined) {
    throw new https.HttpsError("failed-precondition", "The function must be called from an App Check verified app.");
  }

  logger.info("Hello logs!", { structuredData: true });
  const message: Message = {
    text: "Hello from Firebase!",
    code: 200,
  };
  return message;
});

export default helloWorldHandler;
```

with the following test:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions-test";
import * as path from "path";

const projectConfig = {
  projectId: "myproject-id",
};

const testEnv = functions(projectConfig, path.resolve("./flowus-app-dev-fb-admin-sdk-key"));
// has to be after initializing functions
import helloWorldHandler from "../src/functions/helloworld";
import Message from "../src/types/message";

describe('Testing "helloWorld"', () => {
  const helloWorld = testEnv.wrap(helloWorldHandler);

  it("helloWorld does work", async () => {
    const data = {};

    const success: Message = await helloWorld(data);
    expect(success.code).toBe(200);
  });
});
```

When I run it with `yarn test` I receive the following error
`Cannot find module 'firebase-functions/lib/encoder' from 'node_modules/firebase-functions-test/lib/providers/firestore.js'`
Even though my function does not even use firestore in the first place?

Any ideas ?

Comment: Hi @Lucas Goldner , could you please include your `package.json` for us to be able to try to replicate the said issue.

Answer (score 14):

I was facing a similar issue while trying to set up a unit testing environment for firebase cloud functions.
Mainly, after following all the steps on [Firebase's docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing), and running `npm test`
I would get the following error

> Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED] Package subpath './lib/encoder'
> is not defined by "exports"

After stumbling on [Farid's suggestion for this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70183270/error-when-import-firebase-functions-test-when-testing-with-mocha), I realized that, for some reason, `npm i firebase-functions-test` does not install the latest version of the module.

Try `npm i firebase-functions-test@latest`.